# Unique Association :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a many to many :through relationship between a set of classes like so:

```
class Company
  has_many :shares
  has_many :users, :through => :shares, :uniq => true
end

class User
  has_many :shares
  has_many :companys, :through => :shares, uniq => true
end

class Share
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I want to ensure a unique relationship so that a user can only have one share in any one company, which is what I have tried to achieve using the "uniq" argument.

At first I thought this was working, however it seems the behaviour os the "uniq" is to filter on the SELECT of the record, not pre-INSERT so I still get duplicate records in the database, which becomes an issue if I want to start dealing with the :shares association directly, as calling user.shares will return duplicate records if they exist.

Can anyone help with an approach which would force truely uniq relationships? so that if I try adding the second relationships between a user and a company it will reject it and only keep the original?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding this to your `Share` class?

```
validates_uniqueness_of :user, scope: :company
```

Also, in your `User` class I think it should be:

```
has_many :companies, through: :shares
```

I hope that helps.